# Is it there any way to simulate invisible in Facebook chat?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Is it there any way to appear invisible in Facebook? I am aware of how to turn off chats for specific friends, but I want to become invisible.

Is it there any way/messenger to achieve/support this?

Answer (score 1):

If you "turn off chat", everyone will see you as off. Your list will still be there but greyed out (don't 'hide' it). You can still click on anyone in the list. A chat box will open for that person. Likewise if someone starts a chat with you (they'll think you are offline and will be getting the message later), you will get a red notification on the chat (speech bubbles) icon at the top of the page. Click on the red notification>click on the message and a chat window for that person will open. Congratulations and welcome to invisible chat!